# 2 params in C# not compiling

Tags: c#, overloading, parameters

I'm trying to do this:

```
public void CustomMethod(params int[] number,params string[] names)
{
...
}
```

If i delete one of them , there is no problems , any idea of why i can't do this?

I have tried putting a normal parametre in the middle of both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only the last parameter can have `params`. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

The reason is that allowing multiple params would give ambiguity. For example, what would this mean?

```
public void CustomMethod(params int[] foo, params int[] bar)
{
    ...
}

// ...

CustomMethod(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simply not supported. The compiler can't know when one parameter list ends and the next begins.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only write one params parameter in the constructor which shall be the last parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes an argument where the number of arguments is variable.

No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

See Here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=VS.71).aspx